# In DTO Can we use id as String or Long

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, dto

We use DTOs normally to transfer object from one to another form(say JSON), so my doubt is: can I use DTO id as String, or it should be left as long only?

My Model anyhow uses long for id, and I use mapstruct to map object from model to DTO, do I am gonna face any issues later either for POST/GET, if I use id as String, instead of long for DTO class?

Comment: you can have issue while sending some string instead of long as id, i.e. 'test' will be valid but if you use long this will throw an exception. This is something that only you should know, is it good thing to have it. Personally I think you should use long

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that.

You can test it by sending json from Postman and put a long id in inverted string commas and spring will complain for that.